# What does it mean by add an existing msdb role to one of the following SQL Server Agent fixed database roles?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/configure-a-user-to-create-and-manage-sql-server-agent-jobs?view=sql-server-ver15#Security

> To configure a user to create or execute Microsoft SQL Server Agent
> jobs, you must first add an existing SQL Server login or msdb role to
> one of the following SQL Server Agent fixed database roles in the msdb
> database: SQLAgentUserRole, SQLAgentReaderRole, or
> SQLAgentOperatorRole.

I understand that an existing login can be added to one of the above sql server agent fixed database roles.

But what does it mean by **add an existing msdb role to one of the following SQL Server Agent fixed database roles**?

Answer (score 0):

That is either

- a typo (they should have "user" instead of "role")
- or they mean that you create *your own role* in msdb for those who can manage agent ,add users to that role and then add that role to the pre-defined Agent role. One role can "be a member" of another role, ("nested" roles). To me that feels a bit over the edge, so my guess it the above, a typo.